# iframe not displaying properly

Tags: html, iframe

need your help, think something is wrong with this code? It doesn't display anything?

```
<iframe style='overflow: hidden; border: 0; width: 720px; height: 362px' src='<iframe width="600" height="480" frameborder="0" src="http://embed.movshare.net/embed.php?v=ksm4jw0p1e6yv" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have nested two iframes into each other which does not work like you tried. I assume you just want to display `http://embed.movshare.net/embed.php?v=ksm4jw0p1e6yv` in the iframe. The code for this would look something like this:

```
<iframe style="overflow: hidden; border: 0; width: 720px; height: 362px" 
    src="http://embed.movshare.net/embed.php?v=ksm4jw0p1e6yv" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

See it live in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36Knm/).

Answer (score 0):

example iframe from google:

```
<iframe class="gmap" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=212838658933937169734.0004f3360c6126926e728&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-6.947807,107.612513&amp;spn=0,0&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

Your code

```
<iframe style=' border: 0; width: 720px; height: 362px' src='<iframe width="600" height="480" frameborder="0" src="http://embed.movshare.net/embed.php?v=ksm4jw0p1e6yv" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

This is the correction for your code:

```
<iframe src="http://embed.movshare.net/embed.php?v=ksm4jw0p1e6yv" style="border:0;width:720px;height:362px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```